# minimum number of comparisons to find maximum and kth maximum of an arbitrary array of numbers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This question is an extension of the known problem below:

> Find the minimum number of comparisons to find the maximum and minimum
> of an arbitrary array of N numbers.

It turns out we can answer it using tournament tree construction or by using pairs construction(i got these methods from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/)).

I wondered what would be the answer of the following problem:

> Find the minimum number of comparisons to find the maximum and the kth maximum of an arbitrary array of N numbers.

I dont know how to approach this problem. The ideas in my mind are to observe some property on loser/winner arrays at each level of the tournament method, like so:
if array is 8 6 4 3 2 1 5 7, then the winner and loser arrays at each level would be like
winner_1 = [8, 4, 2, 7]
loser_1 = [6, 3, 1, 5]

winner_winner_2 = [8, 7]
loser_winner_2 = [4, 2]
winner_loser_2 = [6, 5]
loser_loser_2 = [3, 1]

winner_winner_winner_3 = [8]
winner_loser_winner_3 = [4]
winner_winner_loser_3 = [6]
winner_loser_loser_3 = [3]

loser_winner_winner_3 = [7]
loser_loser_winner_3 = [2]
loser_winner_loser_3 = [5]
loser_loser_loser_3 = [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/)

Comment: What do you call the Kth maximum ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust let me take the array above as an example: 1st maximum is 8, 2nd maximum is 7, 3rd maximum is 6 and so on. basically, the Kth maximum is the N - Kth element of the array, when it is sorted in non decreasing order. 1 <= K <= N.

Comment: You should say the K *largest* elements then. AFAIK, the problem of the minimum number of comparisons for selection is a difficult one. [See Knuth, Sorting & Searching.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust apologies for the miscommunication. I see. I will check out the section in knuth. Thanks for the advice